# String Duplicate count

Tags: arrays, swift, hashmap

I am trying to prints counts of a duplicate from an input string through the use of hash map. I am not sure why solution is not working. I come from a python background
//Write an efficient program to print all the duplicates and their counts in the input string

```
func letters(inputs: String)->[Character:Int] {
    var result = [Character:Int]()
    for input in inputs {
        if let value = result[input] {
            return [input : value]
        }
        else {
            result[input] = (result[input] ?? 0)+1
        }
    }
    return [:]
}
letters(inputs:"geeksforgeeks")
["e": 1]
```

Comment: The `if` condition in the loop makes no sense, everything you need inside the loop is `result[input] = result[input, default: 0] + 1` and then you need `return result` after the loop

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```swift
func letters(inputs: String) -> [Character:Int] {
    var result = [Character:Int]()
    for input in inputs{
        if let value = result[input] {
            result[input] = value + 1
        }
        else{
            result[input] = 1
        }
    }
    
    return result
}
```

Comment: Thank you, jurah, for the beautiful solution. Would you please check if my description of your code is correct? The if let checks to see if the value exists, if it does, its occurrence is stored in hashmap. If it's not present, it's added to the dictionary. Am I correct?

Comment: @TomHiddleston, Actually most of your description is correct. This is how it works: The first 'if let value" checks if a value exists, the value is a type of integer and this "result[input] = value + 1" just increment the value number. Technically, it rewrites old value with an incremented value. Does it help you to better understand it? :-)